# Why does Darry think that Jez is the one who called him at the diner?

Tags: plot-explanation, jeepers-creepers

In *[Jeepers Creepers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0263488/)* (2001), Darry received a phone call at the diner from a woman who describes to him exactly what he looks like. She explains that she had seen his sister and Darry with lots of cats.

Darry and his sister Trish then visited an old woman with many cats (as mentioned in the phone call). He never mentioned the phone call before her.

Darry and his sister Trish then visited the police station and met a woman called Jez, who he asks about the phone call.

**Why does Darry think Jez is the one who called him over the phone, but not the old woman?**

Comment: Why would Darry think that it would be the old woman who called him in the first place?  Didn't Jez tell him that she sees visions?  Jez also had a pretty distinct voice.  The old woman's voice doesn't sound at all like Jez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Trisha attends the phone call at the diner, the lady on other side asks

> Have you seen the cats yet?

and then said

> You and Darry. I saw you with lots of cats.

If the old lady is the one who called, she could have said "Have you seen my cats?"

And the called lady let them hear the song "Jeeper creepers..", and while you can see a dog lying in the couch.

---

When Jezelle enter the police station she calls Trisha and Darry by their name,

> Trisha? Trisha and Darry, right?

and after that she talk about the bodies down in the cellar, saying she saw them too by dreaming. and then asks

> you see the cats yet? I saw you with all those cats too.

Then Darry figures out and asks

> The Diner. That was you. You called us.?